# pg error after running a simple development command

Tags: typescript, postgresql, graphql, typeorm, pg

I have a very simple typeorm, pg setup and the script is just yarn dev.
I am getting this error somehow.

```js
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: unknown message code: 4a
    at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/dmitriyshin.io/Desktop/Web/React/1. Courses Projects/Uber Clone with TypeScript, Apollo, GraphQL and NodeJS/nuber-server/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:198:16)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/dmitriyshin.io/Desktop/Web/React/1. Courses Projects/Uber Clone with TypeScript, Apollo, GraphQL and NodeJS/nuber-server/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:101:30)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/dmitriyshin.io/Desktop/Web/React/1. Courses Projects/Uber Clone with TypeScript, Apollo, GraphQL and NodeJS/nuber-server/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/index.ts:7:48)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: 4a is ASCII for J, which is not a valid message code. Are you talking to PostgreSQL? If yes, what is in the PostgreSQL log file?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe its Postgres indeed, but I am using the npm package pg

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe where can I find the log file?

Comment: You find the log file in the directory specified by the `log_directory` parameter.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is due of a connection problem with postgres (The connector report a not appropriate message).

Solution : Check your postgres installation and if it's running

Answer (score 0):

This  problem also occurs when you try to connect postrgres with mysql connection string . for more detail [here](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2627).

A temporary solution is to globally  handle uncaughtException

```
    process.on('uncaughtException', e => {
    console.error('An unhandled exception occurred:');
    
    if(  e.message == 'unknown message code: 4a' && e.code  == 'ERR_ASSERTION'){
      console.error( "Postgres error"); 
      // do what you want to do here  
    }
    else{  
    console.error(e);   
    process.exit (1);
      
    }
  
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This error was shown to me when I was using bad credentials to connect to my POSTGRES server. It was resolved as soon as I used the correct user_name, password, port, and host.